# Jupyter Notebook show public IP at startup

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am running a public jupyter notebook on an AWS ec2 instance. When starting the jupyter notebook, how can I get the notebook to give me the public IP address of the instance instead of "localhost"?

```
https://[PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS]:8888/?token=[token]
```

instead of:

```
https://localhost:8888/?token=[token]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can refer to this web page on how to run and secure a public notebook server: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server

Comment: I don't see the answer to my question there. Can you please be more specefic? Thanks!

Comment: How did you start the jupyter notebook? Have you enable jupyter to listen to the public ip?

Comment: Yes, and everything is workin as ist should. I just want to see the outputh with the public ip

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, or at least not easily, because the externally visible IP may not be the internally visible IP, and the machine you are on, likely does not know this. And that's generic of any network/network enabled application.

For example my current ip in  my network is (using `ifconfig`) 10.168.1.63, but my current global ip is `77.200.16.xxx`. My router knows that when it sees an external connection to port 80 from the internet, then it should forward to my machine where the notebook is running. But my machine has no clue about that.

You need to get your public IP from AWS itself.

Comment: I attached an elastic IP to the instance, so I actually know the IP. Where in jupyter's code is the snippet that governs the output of the "jupyter notebook" command? I could simply edit the code to show the elasic IP instead of "localhost", right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `Jupyter notebook` end up  calling NotebookApp.launch_instance; the line displaying the ip or "[all ip on your system]" is [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/ae011a179742a7f4348476beb27faf375b1884fe/notebook/notebookapp.py#L1523)